# Calculate possible image dimensions from pixel count

Tags: python, python-itertools, prime-factoring

If I have an image of width x height pixels I would like to write a function that returns a list of (width, height) tupels with possible ways to rearrange those pixels.

If an image for instance is 87*87 pixels I can factor width and height to get a list of primes:

> [3, 3, 29, 29]

Now I would like to write a function that arranges those primes in all possible ways in groups of 2 to return something like:

> [ (3, 3 * 29 * 29),
>    (29, 3 * 3 * 29),
>    (3 * 3, 29 * 29),
>    (29 * 29, 3 * 3),
>    (3 * 29, 3 * 29),
>    (3 * 3 * 29, 29),
>    (3 * 29 * 29, 3) ]

I left the primes unmultiplied for clarity. Now I did this manually but I would rather have a function do it. And I didn't find an easy way to do it in Python, not even with itertools.

For instance this prints combinations of 3 from the list l:

```
l = [3, 3, 29, 29]
for t in itertools.groupby(itertools.combinations(l, 3)):
    print(t[0])
```

But it doesn't really tell which the fourth element is, the one left out in each combination.

Does anybody have a nice way to calculate all possible 2-tuples from a list of primes. All primes must be used in each tuple, on either side of the comma. Preferably without duplicates (that is what groupby is for in my example).

Comment: Well, you know that `width * height` is always `87 * 87` (let's call that `total_pixels`), so if you calculate `width`, you know that `height = total_pixels / width`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier than what you're trying with prime factors.

```
a = 87*87
print([(x, a//x) for x in range(1, 1+int(math.sqrt(a))) if a % x == 0])
```

Output:

```
[(1, 7569), (3, 2523), (9, 841), (29, 261), (87, 87)]
```

Of course, you also need to flip width and height for each of the possible sizes, except for the square one (if there is a square one).

Even if you have a huge texture (say 16384x16384), this'll be essentially instant.

Comment: Wow, that really works. I guess when factoring you have to try integer division anyway so this is just as fast, and much shorter.